# Want To convert multi dimension array in single array

Tags: php, arrays

want to convert an array into giving example above in PHP

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [101] => Abbottabad
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [102] => Abdul Hakim
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [103] => Ahmed Pur East
        )

)
```

Want to achieve this

```
Array
(
    [101] => Abbottabad
    [102] => Abdul Hakim
    [103] => Ahmed Pur East
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example data contains only a single item per array, you might make use of key and reset inside a foreach loop.

- [key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) Returns the index element of the current array position
- [reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) Returns the value of the first array element

For example:

```
$arrays = [
    [101 => "Abbottabad"],
    [102 => "Abdul Hakim"],
    [103 => "Ahmed Pur East"]
];

$res = [];

foreach($arrays as $array) {
    $res[key($array)] = reset($array);
}

print_r($res);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [101] => Abbottabad
    [102] => Abdul Hakim
    [103] => Ahmed Pur East
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/tDA2s)

**Note** Array keys have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops to iterate to the main array and then the sub arrays where you will be keeping track of the keys and values. Given that the name of your array is `$arr`:

```
$new_arr = array();

foreach($arr as $subarr) {
    foreach($subarr as $key => $value) {
        $new_arr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of if you don't like the look of loops:

```
$array = array(array(101=>'Abbottabad'),array(102=>'Abdul Hakim'),array(103=>'Ahmed Pur East'));
$merged_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array);
print_r($merged_array);

/* Result
Array
(
    [0] => Abbottabad
    [1] => Abdul Hakim
    [2] => Ahmed Pur East
)
*/
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want it like this
Array
(
    [101] => Abbottabad
    [102] => Abdul Hakim
    [103] => Ahmed Pur East
)